# Best data analytic techniques/models for personal project

Tags: machine-learning, analytics, data-analysis

I'm not really sure how to word this and I'm sorry if the formatting is wrong, but I'm trying to get a foundation to be able to tackle this problem myself.

I am trying to develop a prediction algorithm for a set of data of "Hip Surgery Patients" that looks like:

```
Readmission Time | Symptom Code | Symptom Note    |  Related
               6 |         2334 | swelling in hip |     Yes       
              12 |         1324 | anxiety         |     Maybe       
               8 |         2334 | swelling in hip |     Yes       
              30 |         1111 | Headaches       |     No
               3 |         7934 | easily bruising |     Yes
```

For context, doctors can identify whether or not a given "Symptom Code" is related to the "Hip Replacement Surgery" that occurred X days ago. I have about 200 entries in my data set that match this format, and my goal is to be able to match results in the given set as well as predict new results in the "Related" Column (with certainty statistics on predicted results) based on new inputs. For example given:

```
Input:  20 | 2334 | swelling in hip
Output: Yes (90% confidence)
```

I'm very new to Data Analytics and Machine Learning so I would really just like to get some kind of pointers of things to look up or where to get started on my research. I imagine there's an optimal function/model that would handle this best but as I said I'm very new to the topic so I have no clue as to where to start. Since I have a relatively small data set I'm looking for a technique that isn't easily over trained if possible

I really appreciate any help and pointers on where to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your data snippet, it looks like a multiclass classification problem (the 3-classses being Yes, Maybe or No).

Your columns (asides `related`) will be your features which can be reduced to numeric representations. For instance:

For the Symptom Note Feature, you can have a mapping as seen below:

```
Swelling in hip = 1
Anxiety = 2
Swelling = 3
Easily Bruised = 4
```

Obviously this can work if you have a definite number of symptoms in this columns. Machine learning algorithms usually work with numbers so your features will be extracted from the raw data into numeric form. Once that has been done, you can feed the data into a classification algorithm. The naive Bayes algorithm is a great place to start.

Scikit learn (if you can work with python) has a great introductory example on a 3class classification task where all the features are numbers. It tries to classify different types of iris flowers based on the sepal length, sepal width, petal length and petal width.

The full tutorial can be found here: [Supervised learning: predicting an output variable from high-dimensional observations](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html)

Is it feasible to get additional data? If it is, I will suggest you get more. 200 instances is quite small and may not properly represent the feature space. In addition, it will be useful to split the data into a [training and test set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_set) further reducing the quantity used while training. You can also opt for a K-Folds [Cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

Summarily: navigate to that scikit-learn page, try out the flower classification example. Once you're familiar with the environment; your data will need some cleaning and feature extraction. You will need to answer questions like what's the meaning of the `Readmission Time` and `Symptom Code`? Are those values over a specified range with a `special` internal meaning or they are just random numbers assigned like an id.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! This is great. I was having trouble finding resources so I really appreciate this. I'll take a look at all of this and hopefully get somewhere. And I can get more data but only in stages. I would have an advisor who would go through my results saying this result is right/wrong and I would then feed that information to my model and then restart on a new set of 150-200 entries.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend transcribing your data into [ARFF](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) format and then use this with Weka. [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) is a program with many machine learning algorithms you can experiment with, it also has a very simple user interface so is good for beginners! Once you have found an algorithm that works well you can save your trained model and use this to predict new instances!